# Tensorflow 2.0: tf.feature_columns are triggering tf.function retracing warning

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm using tensorflow 2.4.0 to train a dnn but I've been getting the following waring after saving and then loading the model:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function recreate_function.<locals>.restored_function_body at 0x7f14b49933b0> triggered tf.function retracing. 
Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. 
For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. 
For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. 
For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for more details.
```

The surprising thing is that I don't have any custom functions in my code. After debugging by including only one input at a time, I found that these few lines are triggering the warning.

```
categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(col_name, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
feature_columns[col_name] = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column=categorical_column)
```

But there is no way to add the `@tf.function` decorator to this code, since these are not custom functions but `tf.feature_columns`.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to remove the warnings?

**Update:**
This is the complete code:

```
import tempfile

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

col_name = 'vocab'

inputs = {}
inputs[col_name] = tf.keras.layers.Input(name=col_name, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.dtypes.string)

feature_columns = {}
categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(col_name, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
feature_columns[col_name] = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column=categorical_column)

dense_features = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns.values())(inputs)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(dense_features)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
      monitor='val_loss', 
      mode='min', 
      restore_best_weights=True, 
      patience=5
  )

model.fit(
    np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
    np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
    epochs=1,
    callbacks=[es],
)

# Save the model
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
model.save(temp_dir)

# Load it again
tf.saved_model.load(temp_dir)

# ------------------
# ERRORS THAT I GET:
# ------------------
# WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function recreate_function.<locals>.restored_function_body at 0x7f8f810c9050> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
# WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function recreate_function.<locals>.restored_function_body at 0x7f8f810c9680> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
# <tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject at 0x7f8f7a1b80d0>
```

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing``` ?

Comment: @rv123, Is your issue resolved? Else, can you share complete complete code to replicate your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 thank you for your response. We are still having this issue and continue to see the warnings in our logs. I updated the question to include all the code. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!